# Thread/sleep in clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Hellow everyone.

This is a block of code in **events.cljs** file. There is a button on the page that I want when I click that, a text appears on the page and disappear after 3 seconds. Here I wanted to **assoc** the text to the db after clicking the button and dissoc it after 3 seconds but there is an error that `Thread` namespace not found, from `Thread/sleep` line.
Can anyone help me how I should fix that please?

Thank you

```
(rf/reg-event-db
  ::niloofar
  (fn [db [_]]
    (do
      (assoc db :greeting "hi")
      (Thread/sleep 3000)
      (dissoc db :greeting))))
```

Comment: There is no Thread namespace available because Javascript is single-threaded. You won't find the blocking versions of `core.async` operations for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new effect that dissocs the value and use it with [`:dispatch-later`](https://day8.github.io/re-frame/api-builtin-effects/#dispatch-later), something like:

```
(rf/reg-event-fx ::show
  (fn [{db :db} _]
    {:db             (assoc db :greeting "hi")
     :dispatch-later {:ms 3000 :dispatch [::-hide]}))

(rf/reg-event-db ::-hide
  (fn [db _]
    (dissoc db :greeting)))
```